# how to send large data in location.href in java script

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i sent very very large data in location.href it says 400 bad request.

please tell me how to send large data in location.href

my code is

```
location.href='excelExport.do?bound=56.77734375$34.27083595165,105.556640625$8.363692651835823&salesGrowthChecked=false&CensusCheck=false&salesTargetChecked=false&division=20&zone=0,zho0201,ze00201,zn00201,zs00201,zw00201&region=0,rho0201,re00201,rn00201,rs00201,rw00201,rw00202&cluster=0,CAGJ100,CBAN100,CSMC200,CSKE100,CCOR100,CDDC200,CDUP100,CCWB200,CDCH200,CHOCO00,CBAP200,CMMP100,CARJ200,CCWB100,CDHR100,CMMC100,CMMC200,CVID100,CCBH100,CMMH100,CDLU100,CBAP100&territory=0,PATS700,LKNS800,CAL2S40,KANS400,AHMS001,AHMS100,AHMS100,AHMS200,JAI2S40,MHCS300,CKANS40,KANS300,HARS100,CHD1S30,FNT1000,CAL1S30,MHGS200,BANS100,BANS200,BANS800,CBAN100,GHZS300,AHMS600,AHMS900,HYD2S10,CUTS600,PATS300,CHD2S20,AHMS500,MUM2S17,INDS200,CUTS300,MHCS500,CAL1S20,CAL1S40,CAL2S10,CAL2S20,KERS300,CHD2S30,TMN2S10,TMN1S20,TMN2S60,KERS100,CSKE100,TMN1S40,CUTS100,CCOR100,DEL1S10,DEL1S60,DEL1S20,DEL1S30,DEL1S40,DEL1S50,DEL2S10,DEL2S20,DEL2S30,DEL2S40,CDDC200,CUTS400,GHZS400,CAL1S10,LKNS700,HARS500,KANS600,AHMS300,JAI1S40,PATS400,CDUP100,GHZS100,MHPS400,LKNS400,BANS700,HARS400,CAL2S30,CAL2S60,CCWB200,JAI2S30,GHZS500,CHD2S60,HYD2S30,CDCH200,HARS300,HYD1S30,HYD2S40,HYD2S80,HYD2S70,INDS100,INDS500,CMMP100,CPI0000,MHCS700,JAI1S10,JAI2S10,MHCS400,CHD1S40,CHD2S40,CUTS700,KANS500,JAI1S30,KANS100,KANS200,HARS200,FNT1100,FNT1300,MHPS300,CCWB100,JAI2S20,KERS500,HYD2S50,LKNS100,LKNS200,CHD1S10,CDHR100,FNT0900,TMN2S40,CAL2S50,BANS400,GHZS700,CHD1S20,CMMC100,MUM1S10,MUM1S20,MUM1S30,MUM1S40,MUM1S50,MUM2S60,MUM2S70,MUM2S80,MUM2S50,CMUM2S9,PATS200,BANS300,MHCS100,MHCS200,MHGS600,MHGS100,HYD1S60,GHZS600,CHD1S50,CHD2S10,PATS100,PATS500,CCBH100,MHPS800,TMN2S20,MHPS100,MHPS200,MHCS600,HYD1S70,AHMS400,CUTS500,GHZS200,TMN1S30,CUTS200,MHCS800,CHD2S50,BANS600,MHGS300,CAL2S80,PATS600,CHD2S70,AHMS700,AHMS800,FNT1400,MUM2S16,CAL2S70,TMN2S50,HYD1S80,KERS400,TMN2S30,KERS200,JAI1S20,CDLU100,AHMS110,LKNS300,LKNS600,HYD1S40,CBAP100,HYD1S50&wssTerritory=0,GHA0100,CUT7900,PATS700,GUW20O0,CGUW20O,AHM0100,AHM0200,CAHM200,AHM0300,AHM0400,AHM0500,CAHM1F0,AHM3700,AHM0600,AHM0800,CHA0100,HYD24A0,COC7A00,CCOC7F0,HYD17A0,GUW0100,CGUW100,CGHA2F0,GHA0200,AHMS100,CAHM3M0,LUD0100,PUN0100,GUW0200,CGUW200,JAI0100,CJAI1F0,CJAI100,CHA2000,NAS0100,NAG0100,NAG0200,GHA0400,CGHA400,GHA4B00,CKOL100,KANS300,KAN7500,CKAN100,COC10A0,COC10AB,GHA5000,JAI0200,COC6A00,VIJ36A0,NAS0200,HAR0100,HAR2000,NAS3000,NAG0300,CHA0300,NAG4000,SUR0100,CHD1S30,LUD0300,LUD5000,GHA6000,KOL0200,VIJ17A0,CHA0400,HYD28A0,CUT0100,AHM1000,SUR0200,LUC0100,PAT0100,KOL3000,PAT14A0,CHE8A00,HYD30A0,HAR0300,KOL0400,CAL1S30,IND0100,COC1A00,KAN0300,PAT0200,NAS5000,NAS4000,CNAS4A0,CNAS400,KAN10A0,LUC2000,COC21A0,CCOC21A,GHA7000,CCHA500,HUB30A0,LUD6000,GHA8000,HAR5000,KOL5000,IND0200,CUT0200,CUT3000,CKOL600,HAR6000,LUC3000,JAI3000,KAN4000,KOL0700,KAN5000,BANS100,BANS200,BANS800,CBAN17J,CBAN25A,BAN2A00,BAN17A0,CBAN17A,BAN27A0,BAN14A0,CBAN14D,BAN4A00,CBAN100,BAN21A0,CBAN21D,KOL8000,JAI0400,LUC4000,KOL9000,CKOL900,KOL1000,PUN0200,JAI5000,KOL1200,GHA9000,GHZS300,CUT5000,PAT0400,CUT6000,JAI6000,LUD7000,SUR3000,CSUR300,SUR4000,SUR5000,CSUR5A0,GHA1000,NAS6000,HAR7000,KOL1300,CHA7000,KAN6000,LUD8000,CHA8000,CCHA8J0,KAN7000,JAI7000,NAS7000,PAT5000,CPAT500,KOL1500,CKOL150,JAI4600,KOL1600,HYD2S10,HUB15AB,HUB15A0,HUB27A0,KOL1700,CUT7000,CUTS600,CUT8000,PAT6000,IND3000,LUC5000,HYD25A0,CUT9000,HUB16A0,PAT7000,CHA1000,NAG6000,JAI8000,SUR6000,NAG7000,CHD2S20,COI10A0,SUR7000,AHMS050,AHMS500,CSUR7M0,CHA1100,CUT1100,MUM2S17,MUMB010,NAG8000,CNAG800,JAI9000,VIJ21A0,IND0400,JAI1000,MUMB200,HAR8000,IND0500,IND6000,CIND600,IND7000,CIND700,CIND5F0,CUT1200,CCUT120,CUTS300,AHM1100,CAHM11H,CHA1300,NAS8000,HUB23A0,CHUB23D,PAT8000,HUB9A00,GHA1200,JAI1100,CJAI110,CJAI11A,SUR8000,IND8000,KAN8000,CKOL180,HYD44A0,SUR11A0,CUT1300,KOL68A0,GUW3000,KOL1900,SUR9000,SUR1000,CHA1500,GHA1300,JAI1200,KOL2000,IND9000,PAT9000,KOL2700,CAL1S40,CAL2S10,CAL2S20,COC36A0,CCOC35G,CUT1500,NAS9000,CHA1600,KOL2200,CHA1700,CHA1400,CCHA170,KOL2300,CKOL230,GHA1400,NAG1000,COC43A0,PAT1000,CPAT100,CHA1800,HAR1000,COC15A0,CHE20A0,CHE16A0,CHE4A00,CCHE2A0,CHE5A00,CHE29A0,CCHE28P,CCHE17C,CCHE17J,CCHE29M,CHE29B0,CCHE18A,CHE18A0,CHE21A0,CCHE21D,CCHE21A,CHE22A0,CCHE22B,CCHE22Q,CCHE22L,CCHE24K,CHE23A0,CCHE23J,CHE26A0,CHE25A0,CHE24A0,IND1000,IND1100,BAN13A0,CHE9A00,VIJ23A0,COI17A0,VIJ24A0,HUB13A0,VIJ4A00,JAI1300,JAI1400,JAI1500,COC37A0,CCOC15F,CCOC15D,CSKE100,COC5A00,CCOC5A0,CCOI34S,COI34A0,COI37A0,CKOL250,CKOL25J,KOL2600,CLU1000,CHE13A0,VIJ19A0,CUT1700,CCOR100,SUR1100,IND1200,DELB100,SUR1200,SUR1300,CUT1800,SUR1400,IND1300,PAT1100,PAT1200,CPAT120,CKOL28S,IND1400,PUN0300,JAI1600,HUB22A0,AHM1200,GHA1500,CGHA15A,CGHA150,CGHA15J,PAT1300,DELB200,DELA010,CDELA10,DELA200,CDELA20,DELB300,DELA500,CDEL5L0,CDELA5N,CDELA50,DELA700,CDELA7D,CDELA70,DELB400,DELA400,CDELD40,CDELA40,DELA900,DELB500,CDELB50,DELB600,DELB700,CDELD70,CDELB70,DELA100,CDELB3L,GHA1600,CDDC200,DELA300,CDELA30,GHA35A0,CUT1900,LUC6000,IND1500,GHA1700,NAG1100,CUT2000,CCUT20F,HAR1100,IND1600,LUD9000,GUW5000,COI25A0,HYD28B0,CHA30H0,HUB17A0,CUT2100,AHM1300,JAI1700,AHM1400,AHM1500,GUW6000,NAS1000,LUD1000,GUW7000,GUW8000,CGUW8F0,COI1A00,MUMB3A0,GHZS400,CUT2200,JAI1800,NAG1200,KOL3100,CKOL310,COC5300,HAR1200,VIJ35A0,COI18A0,GHA1800,KAN9000,KAN1000,KOL3200,HAR1300,CHAR130,CHAR13O,CLUD110,KAN1100,HAR1400,KAN1200,CHA0200,CCHA200,GHA1900,LUD1300,PAT1400,HUB18A0,PUN7N00,VIJ14A0,AHM1600,AHM1700,CAHM170,JAI1900,HUB21A0,KOL3300,IND1700,CKOL340,PAT1500,CPAT15F,CPAT150,HAR1500,KOL3600,CDUP100,CGHA1G0,LUC7000,CHA2100,CHA2200,CUT2400,PUN4000,CPUN4J0,PUN5000,CPUN500,GUW9000,HYD18A0,SUR1500,HAR1600,LUC8000,KAN1300,AHM1800,NAG1300,PAT1600,VIJ8A00,COI31A0,SUR2500,SUR25A0,LUC9000,LKNS400,LUC1000,VIJ25A0,VIJ29A0,BANS700,HUB24A0,CHUB24A,IND1800,HYD7A00,VIJ11A0,LUD1400,HAR1700,HAR1800,HARS400,LUD1500,GUW4000,CCWB200,GUW1000,CGUW10D,CGUW10F,GUW1100,CGUW110,IND1900,IND2000,JAI2S30,PAT1700,KOL3700,GHA2000,CGHA20F,SUR1600,CHA2300,CHD2S60,HAR1900,HYD2S30,JAI2000,HYD8A00,GHA2100,CGHA210,IND2100,LUC1100,GHA2200,CGHA220,HUB28A0,CDCH200,BAN15A0,GHA2300,HUB31A0,CUT2700,AHM1900,KOL3800,JAI2100,HYD28AB,NAG1400,NAS1100,HAR2100,GUW1200,HUB5A00,IND2200,LUD1600,HUB8A00,COI28A0,KOL3900,CKOL390,HUB26A0,CHUB26F,HYD41A0,CHYD35M,CHYD35A,HYD15A0,HYD12A0,PUN7000,GUW1300,CGUW130,IND2300,IND2400,IND2500,IND2600,CIND26J,CMMP100,COC19A0,KOL4000,IND2700,IND28P0,IND28N0,CIND28B,NAG1500,HYD3A00,LUD1700,PAT1800,JAI2200,CJAI220,CJAI230,JAI2300,JAI2400,JAI2500,CJAI25A,CJAI250,JAI2600,CHA2400,CHA2500,KAN1400,LUD1900,CLUD19D,CLUD19B,GHA18M0,NAS1200,CNAS120,NAS1300,JAI2700,KOL4200,SUR1700,HUB20A0,CCHA260,CHA2600,AHM2000,CUT3100,CUTS700,CUT3200,LUD2000,IND2900,AHM2100,CHA2800,CUT3400,LUC1200,AHM2200,CUT3500,JAI2800,KAN1500,KOL4300,CUT3600,JAI2900,HAR2300,KOL4400,JAI1S30,JAI3100,GUW1400,CGUW140,CUT3700,SUR1800,AHM2300,PAT1900,HAR2400,VIJ40A0,KOL9600,COC2A00,HAR2500,DELA110,KOL4600,MUMB300,HYD33A0,NAG1600,CHE7A00,VIJ30A0,CHA3000,COC50A0,KOL4700,JAI3200,CCOC38D,CCOC18G,KAN1700,KAN1800,CKAN18S,KAN1900,LUD2100,PUN9000,COI12A0,NAG1700,KAN2000,COI23A0,HYD16A0,GUW1500,HAR2600,CHAR260,COC17A0,COI24A0,HUB3A00,COC13A0,CCOC13A,GHA4A00,GHA2400,CHA3100,PAT2000,IND3100,KOL4800,VIJ28A0,COC11A0,CUT4000,PAT2100,LUC10A0,NAG1800,HYD27A0,IND3200,LUD2200,KOL4900,CHA3200,IND3300,GHA2500,PUN1000,GHA2600,GHA2700,PAT2200,JAI3300,CGUW89K,GUW1700,BAN1A00,PUN1100,MHPS300,CPUN11A,CPUN110,CPUN11B,CKOL53N,KOL5300,CCWB100,COC9A00,CCOC9A0,CCOC9L0,KAN2100,CUT4300,NAG1900,CNAG190,GHA2800,JAI3400,CJAI340,JAI2S20,GHA2900,HYD6A00,LUD2300,JAI3500,COC48A0,COC4A00,CCOC4A0,COI5A00,KOL5100,COI21A0,PUN1200,CHA3300,COI35A0,COC47A0,CCOC8K0,HYD5A00,HYD2S50,HAR2700,HAR2800,LUC1300,KAN2200,NAS1400,CUT4500,PUN3000,LUC1400,CLUC140,LUC1500,LUC1600,LKNS100,LUD2400,CLUD240,CDHR100,LUD2500,CLUD250,VIJ12A0,VIJ20A0,PAT2300,COI45A0,COI46A0,COI48A0,CKOL540,HYD2A00,KAN2300,SUR1900,GHA3000,COC24A0,CCOC3A0,KOL5600,CAL2S50,NAS1500,LUD2700,NAG2000,CHA3500,COC26A0,CCOC26F,HYD13A0,VIJ26A0,CHA3600,CCHA360,HAR3000,IND3400,BAN19A0,NAG2100,CHUB4A0,HUB4A00,CHUB4J0,MUMB400,NAS1600,NAS1700,COI4A00,COC45A0,CHA3800,VIJ37A0,GHA3100,COC41A0,LUC1800,CHA3900,KAN2400,COI15A0,GHA3200,CGHA320,HYD1A00,CHYD1A0,AHM2400,KOL5700,IND3500,KOL5800,KAN2500,AHM2500,CLU2000,GHA3300,LUD2800,CHD1S20,CHA4000,PAT4400,PAT2400,GHA3400,CGHA340,AHM2600,IND3600,GUW18N0,CHA4100,PAT2500,LUC1900,LUD3000,CLUD300,CMMC100,PUN8000,MUMA700,MUM1S40,MUMB3AM,MUMA100,CUMAS10,MUMA200,CMUMA20,MUMB500,CMUMB50,CUMB5Y0,CUMB5K0,MUMB600,CMUMB60,MUMB700,CUMB7L0,CUMB7A0,MUMA500,CUM5AD0,MUMB802,MUMB801,CMUMB80,CMUMA70,MUMA400,MUMB900,GHA3500,PAT2600,CPAT260,BAN11A0,CBAN11G,CBAN11J,CHA4200,CCHA420,CHA4300,SUR2000,CNAG31M,GUW1800,JAI3600,IND3700,COI38A0,NAG9000,NAG2400,CNAG240,CNAG24A,NAG2500,NAG2300,CNAG230,NAG2200,NAG3800,CNAG22F,CHA4400,GUW1900,CGUW190,GHA3600,GHA3700,LUD3100,CHA4500,GUW2000,COI3A00,NAS1800,CNAS180,NAS1900,HYD19A0,CHA4600,HAR3100,HAR3200,VIJ31A0,HAR3300,NAS2000,CNAS20A,CNAS200,NAS2100,MHGS100,JAI3700,SUR2100,PAT2700,LUD3200,IND3800,VIJ5A00,VIJ6A00,CHE10A0,CCHE10D,COC22AB,HYD26A0,DELB800,CDELB80,GUW2100,CGUW210,VIJ22A0,CVIJ22A,COI27A0,KAN2600,NAS2200,NAS2300,LUC2100,VIJ38A0,COI16A0,AHM2700,KOL7800,MUMB100,COC3A00,CCOC3D0,LUC2200,JAI3800,HAR3400,HAR3500,NAS2400,HAR3600,MUMB110,CHA4700,NAS2500,COI39A0,IND3900,NAG2600,COC40A0,NAS2600,AHM2800,NAG2700,COC25A0,CCOC25A,CHA4900,CCHA490,CCHA49M,PAT3300,PAT3400,PATS100,PATS500,PAT2900,CCBH100,PAT3000,CPAT30F,PAT3100,CPAT31H,PAT3200,CHA5000,COI22A0,HAR3800,LUD3300,PUN1300,LUD3400,KOL6000,JAI3900,GHA3800,CPUN140,PUN14A0,PUN1400,GHA3900,MUMB120,COI9A00,CHE6A00,CCHE6Q0,CCHE6K0,AHM2900,CAHM29F,KOL6100,KAN2700,VIJ18A0,COI2A00,MHPS100,PUN1500,PUN1700,CPUN17F,CPUN170,CPUN15K,CPUN15L,CPUN15M,PUN1800,CPUN19A,CUT5100,PAT3500,KOL6200,NAG2800,HUB6A00,CHA26N0,CUT5200,LUC2300,HUB25A0,KOL6300,NAG2900,LUD3500,NAG3000,CNAG300,VIJ7A00,COI19A0,JAI4500,PUN2000,CAHM30H,AHM3000,NAG3100,CHA5100,CCHA510,CHA35A0,CUT5400,COI8A00,GHA4000,GHA4100,CHA5200,CHA5300,KOL6500,CUT5500,CUTS500,CCUT550,HUB29A0,HAR3900,IND4000,PUN2100,PAT3600,VIJ39A0,CUT5600,LUC2400,IND4100,HAR4000,GHA4200,CGHA420,LUC2500,CHA5500,HAR4100,GHA4300,CGHA43S,CHA5600,CCHA560,CUT5700,GHA4400,CGHA44S,HUB19A0,IND4200,GHA4500,CGHA450,GHZS200,PAT3700,CPAT370,GHA4600,CGHA460,LUD4200,COI54A0,KOL7000,VIJ16A0,HAR4200,CHAR420,VIJ41A0,CHA5700,PAT3800,CUT5900,GHA4700,PUN2200,LUD3600,HYD45A0,PUN2300,CHA5800,CCHA580,CHA9200,BAN36A0,PAT3900,PUN2400,IND4300,VIJ31AS,HYD31C0,HYD23A0,CHYD23D,IND4400,IND4500,HAR4300,IND4600,LUC2600,LUC2700,GHA4800,NAG3200,CHA5900,GUW2200,CGUW220,CCHA600,CHA6100,HUB7A00,NAS2700,IND4700,GUW2300,NAS2800,PUN2500,KOL7100,HYD40A0,JAI4000,GUW21N0,GUW2400,CGUW240,KOL7200,CAL2S80,KOL7300,CKOL730,SUR2200,CSUR220,KOL7400,CHA6200,HAR4400,HUB2A00,PAT4000,LUC2800,COI11A0,PAT4100,PATS600,CPAT410,HAR4500,KOL7500,HAR4600,JAI4100,VIJ44A0,CHA6300,CCHA63F,CHD2S70,CCHA630,CCHA63C,CCHA63K,CCHA63L,CCHA63I,CHA6400,KAN2800,LUD3700,KAN2900,JAI4200,CHA6500,CHA6600,AHMS080,SUR2300,SUR2400,CSUR240,CSUR250,JAI4300,AHM3200,VIJ34A0,HYD10A0,CUT6200,PUN2600,LUD3800,COI33A0,VIJ10A0,LUD3900,HAR4700,VIJ2A00,GUW2500,COC20A0,MUMB14U,CUM14G0,MUMB13N,COI26A0,COI20A0,COC30A0,IND4800,GUW2600,CAL2S70,COI40A0,COI32A0,CVIJ33A,VIJ33A0,COI6A00,COC46A0,CHE11A0,COI29A0,HAR4800,KOL7700,CKOL770,JAI4400,CCOC8L0,COC8A00,CCOC8U0,COC8AB0,COI43A0,CCOI43E,CCOC29B,CCOC29K,COC22A0,COC29A0,BAN18A0,VIJ9A00,GUW2700,COI42A0,NAS2900,CHA6700,HUB1A00,IND4900,MUMB150,NAG3300,CHA6800,AHM3400,KAN3000,AHM3500,CDLU100,SUR2600,CSUR260,CCOC540,SUR2700,CSUR27F,SUR2800,CLUC30F,LUC2900,LUC30P0,MUMB160,CUMB160,CHE14A0,SUR2900,CLUD400,IND5000,HYD15B0,VIJ1AB0,CVIJ1J0,VIJ1A00,CVIJ1F0,CBAP100,GHA4900,CHE1A00,VIJ27A0,MUMB170,CUMB170,AHM3600,PUN2700,HYD1S50,VIJ15A0,CVIJ15D,CVIJ15S,VIJ3A00,PUN2800,NAG3400,HYD9A00,CHYD9A0,NAG3500,NAG3600,COC14A0,HAR4900,NAG3700,HYD38A0,LUD4100,CHA6900&freeWssTerritory=ENTER WSS TTY NAME&nmg=-1&product=-1&sku=-1&salesExceptionchk=true&SEOSGchk=true&act=SEExport&sub_division=-1';
```

please help................

i did it to send like post again its not working same problem persist. like   var form =

```
document.getElementById("exportForm");
                form.method = "post";
                form.action = 'excelExport.do?bound=56.77734375$34.27083595165,105.556640625$8.363692651835823&salesGrowthChecked=false&CensusCheck=false&salesTargetChecked=false&division=20&zone=0,zho0201,ze00201,zn00201,zs00201,zw00201&region=0,rho0201,re00201,rn00201,rs00201,rw00201,rw00202&cluster=0,CAGJ100,CBAN100,CSMC200,CSKE100,CCOR100,CDDC200,CDUP100,CCWB200,CDCH200,CHOCO00,CBAP200,CMMP100,CARJ200,CCWB100,CDHR100,CMMC100,CMMC200,CVID100,CCBH100,CMMH100,CDLU100,CBAP100&territory=0,PATS700,LKNS800,CAL2S40,KANS400,AHMS001,AHMS100,AHMS100,AHMS200,JAI2S40,MHCS300,CKANS40,KANS300,HARS100,CHD1S30,FNT1000,CAL1S30,MHGS200,BANS100,BANS200,BANS800,CBAN100,GHZS300,AHMS600,AHMS900,HYD2S10,CUTS600,PATS300,CHD2S20,AHMS500,MUM2S17,INDS200,CUTS300,MHCS500,CAL1S20,CAL1S40,CAL2S10,CAL2S20,KERS300,CHD2S30,TMN2S10,TMN1S20,TMN2S60,KERS100,CSKE100,TMN1S40,CUTS100,CCOR100,DEL1S10,DEL1S60,DEL1S20,DEL1S30,DEL1S40,DEL1S50,DEL2S10,DEL2S20,DEL2S30,DEL2S40,CDDC200,CUTS400,GHZS400,CAL1S10,LKNS700,HARS500,KANS600,AHMS300,JAI1S40,PATS400,CDUP100,GHZS100,MHPS400,LKNS400,BANS700,HARS400,CAL2S30,CAL2S60,CCWB200,JAI2S30,GHZS500,CHD2S60,HYD2S30,CDCH200,HARS300,HYD1S30,HYD2S40,HYD2S80,HYD2S70,INDS100,INDS500,CMMP100,CPI0000,MHCS700,JAI1S10,JAI2S10,MHCS400,CHD1S40,CHD2S40,CUTS700,KANS500,JAI1S30,KANS100,KANS200,HARS200,FNT1100,FNT1300,MHPS300,CCWB100,JAI2S20,KERS500,HYD2S50,LKNS100,LKNS200,CHD1S10,CDHR100,FNT0900,TMN2S40,CAL2S50,BANS400,GHZS700,CHD1S20,CMMC100,MUM1S10,MUM1S20,MUM1S30,MUM1S40,MUM1S50,MUM2S60,MUM2S70,MUM2S80,MUM2S50,CMUM2S9,PATS200,BANS300,MHCS100,MHCS200,MHGS600,MHGS100,HYD1S60,GHZS600,CHD1S50,CHD2S10,PATS100,PATS500,CCBH100,MHPS800,TMN2S20,MHPS100,MHPS200,MHCS600,HYD1S70,AHMS400,CUTS500,GHZS200,TMN1S30,CUTS200,MHCS800,CHD2S50,BANS600,MHGS300,CAL2S80,PATS600,CHD2S70,AHMS700,AHMS800,FNT1400,MUM2S16,CAL2S70,TMN2S50,HYD1S80,KERS400,TMN2S30,KERS200,JAI1S20,CDLU100,AHMS110,LKNS300,LKNS600,HYD1S40,CBAP100,HYD1S50&wssTerritory=0,GHA0100,CUT7900,PATS700,GUW20O0,CGUW20O,AHM0100,AHM0200,CAHM200,AHM0300,AHM0400,AHM0500,CAHM1F0,AHM3700,AHM0600,AHM0800,CHA0100,HYD24A0,COC7A00,CCOC7F0,HYD17A0,GUW0100,CGUW100,CGHA2F0,GHA0200,AHMS100,CAHM3M0,LUD0100,PUN0100,GUW0200,CGUW200,JAI0100,CJAI1F0,CJAI100,CHA2000,NAS0100,NAG0100,NAG0200,GHA0400,CGHA400,GHA4B00,CKOL100,KANS300,KAN7500,CKAN100,COC10A0,COC10AB,GHA5000,JAI0200,COC6A00,VIJ36A0,NAS0200,HAR0100,HAR2000,NAS3000,NAG0300,CHA0300,NAG4000,SUR0100,CHD1S30,LUD0300,LUD5000,GHA6000,KOL0200,VIJ17A0,CHA0400,HYD28A0,CUT0100,AHM1000,SUR0200,LUC0100,PAT0100,KOL3000,PAT14A0,CHE8A00,HYD30A0,HAR0300,KOL0400,CAL1S30,IND0100,COC1A00,KAN0300,PAT0200,NAS5000,NAS4000,CNAS4A0,CNAS400,KAN10A0,LUC2000,COC21A0,CCOC21A,GHA7000,CCHA500,HUB30A0,LUD6000,GHA8000,HAR5000,KOL5000,IND0200,CUT0200,CUT3000,CKOL600,HAR6000,LUC3000,JAI3000,KAN4000,KOL0700,KAN5000,BANS100,BANS200,BANS800,CBAN17J,CBAN25A,BAN2A00,BAN17A0,CBAN17A,BAN27A0,BAN14A0,CBAN14D,BAN4A00,CBAN100,BAN21A0,CBAN21D,KOL8000,JAI0400,LUC4000,KOL9000,CKOL900,KOL1000,PUN0200,JAI5000,KOL1200,GHA9000,GHZS300,CUT5000,PAT0400,CUT6000,JAI6000,LUD7000,SUR3000,CSUR300,SUR4000,SUR5000,CSUR5A0,GHA1000,NAS6000,HAR7000,KOL1300,CHA7000,KAN6000,LUD8000,CHA8000,CCHA8J0,KAN7000,JAI7000,NAS7000,PAT5000,CPAT500,KOL1500,CKOL150,JAI4600,KOL1600,HYD2S10,HUB15AB,HUB15A0,HUB27A0,KOL1700,CUT7000,CUTS600,CUT8000,PAT6000,IND3000,LUC5000,HYD25A0,CUT9000,HUB16A0,PAT7000,CHA1000,NAG6000,JAI8000,SUR6000,NAG7000,CHD2S20,COI10A0,SUR7000,AHMS050,AHMS500,CSUR7M0,CHA1100,CUT1100,MUM2S17,MUMB010,NAG8000,CNAG800,JAI9000,VIJ21A0,IND0400,JAI1000,MUMB200,HAR8000,IND0500,IND6000,CIND600,IND7000,CIND700,CIND5F0,CUT1200,CCUT120,CUTS300,AHM1100,CAHM11H,CHA1300,NAS8000,HUB23A0,CHUB23D,PAT8000,HUB9A00,GHA1200,JAI1100,CJAI110,CJAI11A,SUR8000,IND8000,KAN8000,CKOL180,HYD44A0,SUR11A0,CUT1300,KOL68A0,GUW3000,KOL1900,SUR9000,SUR1000,CHA1500,GHA1300,JAI1200,KOL2000,IND9000,PAT9000,KOL2700,CAL1S40,CAL2S10,CAL2S20,COC36A0,CCOC35G,CUT1500,NAS9000,CHA1600,KOL2200,CHA1700,CHA1400,CCHA170,KOL2300,CKOL230,GHA1400,NAG1000,COC43A0,PAT1000,CPAT100,CHA1800,HAR1000,COC15A0,CHE20A0,CHE16A0,CHE4A00,CCHE2A0,CHE5A00,CHE29A0,CCHE28P,CCHE17C,CCHE17J,CCHE29M,CHE29B0,CCHE18A,CHE18A0,CHE21A0,CCHE21D,CCHE21A,CHE22A0,CCHE22B,CCHE22Q,CCHE22L,CCHE24K,CHE23A0,CCHE23J,CHE26A0,CHE25A0,CHE24A0,IND1000,IND1100,BAN13A0,CHE9A00,VIJ23A0,COI17A0,VIJ24A0,HUB13A0,VIJ4A00,JAI1300,JAI1400,JAI1500,COC37A0,CCOC15F,CCOC15D,CSKE100,COC5A00,CCOC5A0,CCOI34S,COI34A0,COI37A0,CKOL250,CKOL25J,KOL2600,CLU1000,CHE13A0,VIJ19A0,CUT1700,CCOR100,SUR1100,IND1200,DELB100,SUR1200,SUR1300,CUT1800,SUR1400,IND1300,PAT1100,PAT1200,CPAT120,CKOL28S,IND1400,PUN0300,JAI1600,HUB22A0,AHM1200,GHA1500,CGHA15A,CGHA150,CGHA15J,PAT1300,DELB200,DELA010,CDELA10,DELA200,CDELA20,DELB300,DELA500,CDEL5L0,CDELA5N,CDELA50,DELA700,CDELA7D,CDELA70,DELB400,DELA400,CDELD40,CDELA40,DELA900,DELB500,CDELB50,DELB600,DELB700,CDELD70,CDELB70,DELA100,CDELB3L,GHA1600,CDDC200,DELA300,CDELA30,GHA35A0,CUT1900,LUC6000,IND1500,GHA1700,NAG1100,CUT2000,CCUT20F,HAR1100,IND1600,LUD9000,GUW5000,COI25A0,HYD28B0,CHA30H0,HUB17A0,CUT2100,AHM1300,JAI1700,AHM1400,AHM1500,GUW6000,NAS1000,LUD1000,GUW7000,GUW8000,CGUW8F0,COI1A00,MUMB3A0,GHZS400,CUT2200,JAI1800,NAG1200,KOL3100,CKOL310,COC5300,HAR1200,VIJ35A0,COI18A0,GHA1800,KAN9000,KAN1000,KOL3200,HAR1300,CHAR130,CHAR13O,CLUD110,KAN1100,HAR1400,KAN1200,CHA0200,CCHA200,GHA1900,LUD1300,PAT1400,HUB18A0,PUN7N00,VIJ14A0,AHM1600,AHM1700,CAHM170,JAI1900,HUB21A0,KOL3300,IND1700,CKOL340,PAT1500,CPAT15F,CPAT150,HAR1500,KOL3600,CDUP100,CGHA1G0,LUC7000,CHA2100,CHA2200,CUT2400,PUN4000,CPUN4J0,PUN5000,CPUN500,GUW9000,HYD18A0,SUR1500,HAR1600,LUC8000,KAN1300,AHM1800,NAG1300,PAT1600,VIJ8A00,COI31A0,SUR2500,SUR25A0,LUC9000,LKNS400,LUC1000,VIJ25A0,VIJ29A0,BANS700,HUB24A0,CHUB24A,IND1800,HYD7A00,VIJ11A0,LUD1400,HAR1700,HAR1800,HARS400,LUD1500,GUW4000,CCWB200,GUW1000,CGUW10D,CGUW10F,GUW1100,CGUW110,IND1900,IND2000,JAI2S30,PAT1700,KOL3700,GHA2000,CGHA20F,SUR1600,CHA2300,CHD2S60,HAR1900,HYD2S30,JAI2000,HYD8A00,GHA2100,CGHA210,IND2100,LUC1100,GHA2200,CGHA220,HUB28A0,CDCH200,BAN15A0,GHA2300,HUB31A0,CUT2700,AHM1900,KOL3800,JAI2100,HYD28AB,NAG1400,NAS1100,HAR2100,GUW1200,HUB5A00,IND2200,LUD1600,HUB8A00,COI28A0,KOL3900,CKOL390,HUB26A0,CHUB26F,HYD41A0,CHYD35M,CHYD35A,HYD15A0,HYD12A0,PUN7000,GUW1300,CGUW130,IND2300,IND2400,IND2500,IND2600,CIND26J,CMMP100,COC19A0,KOL4000,IND2700,IND28P0,IND28N0,CIND28B,NAG1500,HYD3A00,LUD1700,PAT1800,JAI2200,CJAI220,CJAI230,JAI2300,JAI2400,JAI2500,CJAI25A,CJAI250,JAI2600,CHA2400,CHA2500,KAN1400,LUD1900,CLUD19D,CLUD19B,GHA18M0,NAS1200,CNAS120,NAS1300,JAI2700,KOL4200,SUR1700,HUB20A0,CCHA260,CHA2600,AHM2000,CUT3100,CUTS700,CUT3200,LUD2000,IND2900,AHM2100,CHA2800,CUT3400,LUC1200,AHM2200,CUT3500,JAI2800,KAN1500,KOL4300,CUT3600,JAI2900,HAR2300,KOL4400,JAI1S30,JAI3100,GUW1400,CGUW140,CUT3700,SUR1800,AHM2300,PAT1900,HAR2400,VIJ40A0,KOL9600,COC2A00,HAR2500,DELA110,KOL4600,MUMB300,HYD33A0,NAG1600,CHE7A00,VIJ30A0,CHA3000,COC50A0,KOL4700,JAI3200,CCOC38D,CCOC18G,KAN1700,KAN1800,CKAN18S,KAN1900,LUD2100,PUN9000,COI12A0,NAG1700,KAN2000,COI23A0,HYD16A0,GUW1500,HAR2600,CHAR260,COC17A0,COI24A0,HUB3A00,COC13A0,CCOC13A,GHA4A00,GHA2400,CHA3100,PAT2000,IND3100,KOL4800,VIJ28A0,COC11A0,CUT4000,PAT2100,LUC10A0,NAG1800,HYD27A0,IND3200,LUD2200,KOL4900,CHA3200,IND3300,GHA2500,PUN1000,GHA2600,GHA2700,PAT2200,JAI3300,CGUW89K,GUW1700,BAN1A00,PUN1100,MHPS300,CPUN11A,CPUN110,CPUN11B,CKOL53N,KOL5300,CCWB100,COC9A00,CCOC9A0,CCOC9L0,KAN2100,CUT4300,NAG1900,CNAG190,GHA2800,JAI3400,CJAI340,JAI2S20,GHA2900,HYD6A00,LUD2300,JAI3500,COC48A0,COC4A00,CCOC4A0,COI5A00,KOL5100,COI21A0,PUN1200,CHA3300,COI35A0,COC47A0,CCOC8K0,HYD5A00,HYD2S50,HAR2700,HAR2800,LUC1300,KAN2200,NAS1400,CUT4500,PUN3000,LUC1400,CLUC140,LUC1500,LUC1600,LKNS100,LUD2400,CLUD240,CDHR100,LUD2500,CLUD250,VIJ12A0,VIJ20A0,PAT2300,COI45A0,COI46A0,COI48A0,CKOL540,HYD2A00,KAN2300,SUR1900,GHA3000,COC24A0,CCOC3A0,KOL5600,CAL2S50,NAS1500,LUD2700,NAG2000,CHA3500,COC26A0,CCOC26F,HYD13A0,VIJ26A0,CHA3600,CCHA360,HAR3000,IND3400,BAN19A0,NAG2100,CHUB4A0,HUB4A00,CHUB4J0,MUMB400,NAS1600,NAS1700,COI4A00,COC45A0,CHA3800,VIJ37A0,GHA3100,COC41A0,LUC1800,CHA3900,KAN2400,COI15A0,GHA3200,CGHA320,HYD1A00,CHYD1A0,AHM2400,KOL5700,IND3500,KOL5800,KAN2500,AHM2500,CLU2000,GHA3300,LUD2800,CHD1S20,CHA4000,PAT4400,PAT2400,GHA3400,CGHA340,AHM2600,IND3600,GUW18N0,CHA4100,PAT2500,LUC1900,LUD3000,CLUD300,CMMC100,PUN8000,MUMA700,MUM1S40,MUMB3AM,MUMA100,CUMAS10,MUMA200,CMUMA20,MUMB500,CMUMB50,CUMB5Y0,CUMB5K0,MUMB600,CMUMB60,MUMB700,CUMB7L0,CUMB7A0,MUMA500,CUM5AD0,MUMB802,MUMB801,CMUMB80,CMUMA70,MUMA400,MUMB900,GHA3500,PAT2600,CPAT260,BAN11A0,CBAN11G,CBAN11J,CHA4200,CCHA420,CHA4300,SUR2000,CNAG31M,GUW1800,JAI3600,IND3700,COI38A0,NAG9000,NAG2400,CNAG240,CNAG24A,NAG2500,NAG2300,CNAG230,NAG2200,NAG3800,CNAG22F,CHA4400,GUW1900,CGUW190,GHA3600,GHA3700,LUD3100,CHA4500,GUW2000,COI3A00,NAS1800,CNAS180,NAS1900,HYD19A0,CHA4600,HAR3100,HAR3200,VIJ31A0,HAR3300,NAS2000,CNAS20A,CNAS200,NAS2100,MHGS100,JAI3700,SUR2100,PAT2700,LUD3200,IND3800,VIJ5A00,VIJ6A00,CHE10A0,CCHE10D,COC22AB,HYD26A0,DELB800,CDELB80,GUW2100,CGUW210,VIJ22A0,CVIJ22A,COI27A0,KAN2600,NAS2200,NAS2300,LUC2100,VIJ38A0,COI16A0,AHM2700,KOL7800,MUMB100,COC3A00,CCOC3D0,LUC2200,JAI3800,HAR3400,HAR3500,NAS2400,HAR3600,MUMB110,CHA4700,NAS2500,COI39A0,IND3900,NAG2600,COC40A0,NAS2600,AHM2800,NAG2700,COC25A0,CCOC25A,CHA4900,CCHA490,CCHA49M,PAT3300,PAT3400,PATS100,PATS500,PAT2900,CCBH100,PAT3000,CPAT30F,PAT3100,CPAT31H,PAT3200,CHA5000,COI22A0,HAR3800,LUD3300,PUN1300,LUD3400,KOL6000,JAI3900,GHA3800,CPUN140,PUN14A0,PUN1400,GHA3900,MUMB120,COI9A00,CHE6A00,CCHE6Q0,CCHE6K0,AHM2900,CAHM29F,KOL6100,KAN2700,VIJ18A0,COI2A00,MHPS100,PUN1500,PUN1700,CPUN17F,CPUN170,CPUN15K,CPUN15L,CPUN15M,PUN1800,CPUN19A,CUT5100,PAT3500,KOL6200,NAG2800,HUB6A00,CHA26N0,CUT5200,LUC2300,HUB25A0,KOL6300,NAG2900,LUD3500,NAG3000,CNAG300,VIJ7A00,COI19A0,JAI4500,PUN2000,CAHM30H,AHM3000,NAG3100,CHA5100,CCHA510,CHA35A0,CUT5400,COI8A00,GHA4000,GHA4100,CHA5200,CHA5300,KOL6500,CUT5500,CUTS500,CCUT550,HUB29A0,HAR3900,IND4000,PUN2100,PAT3600,VIJ39A0,CUT5600,LUC2400,IND4100,HAR4000,GHA4200,CGHA420,LUC2500,CHA5500,HAR4100,GHA4300,CGHA43S,CHA5600,CCHA560,CUT5700,GHA4400,CGHA44S,HUB19A0,IND4200,GHA4500,CGHA450,GHZS200,PAT3700,CPAT370,GHA4600,CGHA460,LUD4200,COI54A0,KOL7000,VIJ16A0,HAR4200,CHAR420,VIJ41A0,CHA5700,PAT3800,CUT5900,GHA4700,PUN2200,LUD3600,HYD45A0,PUN2300,CHA5800,CCHA580,CHA9200,BAN36A0,PAT3900,PUN2400,IND4300,VIJ31AS,HYD31C0,HYD23A0,CHYD23D,IND4400,IND4500,HAR4300,IND4600,LUC2600,LUC2700,GHA4800,NAG3200,CHA5900,GUW2200,CGUW220,CCHA600,CHA6100,HUB7A00,NAS2700,IND4700,GUW2300,NAS2800,PUN2500,KOL7100,HYD40A0,JAI4000,GUW21N0,GUW2400,CGUW240,KOL7200,CAL2S80,KOL7300,CKOL730,SUR2200,CSUR220,KOL7400,CHA6200,HAR4400,HUB2A00,PAT4000,LUC2800,COI11A0,PAT4100,PATS600,CPAT410,HAR4500,KOL7500,HAR4600,JAI4100,VIJ44A0,CHA6300,CCHA63F,CHD2S70,CCHA630,CCHA63C,CCHA63K,CCHA63L,CCHA63I,CHA6400,KAN2800,LUD3700,KAN2900,JAI4200,CHA6500,CHA6600,AHMS080,SUR2300,SUR2400,CSUR240,CSUR250,JAI4300,AHM3200,VIJ34A0,HYD10A0,CUT6200,PUN2600,LUD3800,COI33A0,VIJ10A0,LUD3900,HAR4700,VIJ2A00,GUW2500,COC20A0,MUMB14U,CUM14G0,MUMB13N,COI26A0,COI20A0,COC30A0,IND4800,GUW2600,CAL2S70,COI40A0,COI32A0,CVIJ33A,VIJ33A0,COI6A00,COC46A0,CHE11A0,COI29A0,HAR4800,KOL7700,CKOL770,JAI4400,CCOC8L0,COC8A00,CCOC8U0,COC8AB0,COI43A0,CCOI43E,CCOC29B,CCOC29K,COC22A0,COC29A0,BAN18A0,VIJ9A00,GUW2700,COI42A0,NAS2900,CHA6700,HUB1A00,IND4900,MUMB150,NAG3300,CHA6800,AHM3400,KAN3000,AHM3500,CDLU100,SUR2600,CSUR260,CCOC540,SUR2700,CSUR27F,SUR2800,CLUC30F,LUC2900,LUC30P0,MUMB160,CUMB160,CHE14A0,SUR2900,CLUD400,IND5000,HYD15B0,VIJ1AB0,CVIJ1J0,VIJ1A00,CVIJ1F0,CBAP100,GHA4900,CHE1A00,VIJ27A0,MUMB170,CUMB170,AHM3600,PUN2700,HYD1S50,VIJ15A0,CVIJ15D,CVIJ15S,VIJ3A00,PUN2800,NAG3400,HYD9A00,CHYD9A0,NAG3500,NAG3600,COC14A0,HAR4900,NAG3700,HYD38A0,LUD4100,CHA6900&freeWssTerritory=ENTER WSS TTY NAME&nmg=-1&product=-1&sku=-1&salesExceptionchk=true&SEOSGchk=true&act=SEExport&sub_division=-1';

                form.submit();
```

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request

Comment: Also: consider switching to a POST request instead.

Comment: will you tell me how to send data in post with location.href. please not to tell to use form.

Comment: How are you building up your current querystring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2659952/631652) for limit of GET data. You can try to call that page by POST parameters.

Reference from `gvee` comment

Comment: will you tell me how to send data in post with location.href. please not to tell to use form.

Comment: You can use AJAX POST then redirect.

Comment: i did it to send like post again its not working same problem persist.

Comment: will you try to understand me with an example ajax post then redirect.redirect page will get all post parameters value.????

Comment: @neerajbharti Yes, for the next time when you redirect it will not consider POST parameters, so final alternative is `<form>` tag.